# Should I say in my website that my focus is to study grad school?

Tags: websites, leave

I am looking for a job to fill the gap before I go to grad school. I have built a personal website to sell myself better. Currently, at the homepage, I write that

> my objective is to continue my study in graduate level

Would this sentence harm my chance to get a job? After all, I still want to be honest and let them know that I'm going to leave the job after the gap ends. However, I do understand that if it's not beneficial for me, I can hide that information.

I will have 6 free months ahead if I can find a scholarship this year, or 18 months if I fail to success.

Comment: This type of information should be apparent on your CV, not just your website. I wouldn't guarantee that any hiring manager would go to your personal website to get additional information about your career goals.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't write that.

First of all, you need to understand what the purpose of your CV / website is, and once you understand what its purpose is it will be clear to you why that is a bad idea.

It's a common misperception that your CV is to land a job. It isn't. Your CV's function is to get you job interviews. Your CV is to get yourself into a room with the recruiter. Period. Once you are with a recruiter, only then are you talking about getting an actual job.

Therefore, your CV / website should only contain whatever relevant and truthful information that will entice a recruiter into interviewing you. Writing that you need a gap-filler job is not a reason to hire you, it's a reason **not** to hire you. You can bring up that stuff once you have an interview and the recruiter has already met you, and you're still being 100% honest, but you're revealing it at a time where it's more politically convenient for you.

Comment: As a recruiter, I would be pretty ticked off if the guy I was interviewing for a job i expected him to hold for a few years suddenly told me he was only planning on working for 6 months.  Not being upfront with that information isn't going to win him any favors.

Comment: Namfuak, that may be, but chances are you wouldn't be interviewing him in the first place if he gave that detail upfront. You shouldn't be giving reasons-not-to-hire-you in a CV, just like you don't mention car mileage in a sports car advertising.

Comment: OK, so instead of not getting an interview at all I've wasted my time and the interviewer's by getting an interview that won't result in a hire.  A person buying a sports car probably don't care that much about the mileage, a company cares greatly about whether or not the person they are hiring will work for them long enough to be worth the hire.

Comment: To be blunt, wasting a recruiter's time is not relevant to a candidate. Not when one already wastes several hours on an application only for it to be rejected in 30 seconds by a recruiter.

It might be a relevant detail, or it might not be relevant detail, the point is that's what the job interview is for. Cardinal rule, don't put any information on any advertising (CV or otherwise) which might rule you out of being even considered.

The question being asked is not what is most convienient for a recruiter, the question is the most effective way for a candidate of landing a job.

Answer (score -1):

You should be upfront about what your objectives are in finding a job, so putting this on your website should be fine.  The positions you are looking for are temporary anyway, whether or not the employer knows why you are only looking for a temp job is not as important.  That said, it may be useful information to the employer - if they like you, they might be willing to work out a long term, part time position while you go to school.

As pointed out in comments, regardless of whether you give the reason, the fact that you are looking for a temporary job only should be on your CV, to avoid wasting your time and the time of the company.  It may even be that a company advertising a long-term position is willing to hire you temporarily to fill the gap, especially if you already have useful skills, but it's less likely that that will happen if they only find out you want a short-term job at the interview.